# A better word/phrase to describe "a more..." in a scientific paper

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, science, academia, scientific-language

I am writing a scientific paper on how a cancer staging system *may* be improved. However, I am a non-native English speaker, and I am concerned that my current title reflects that too much.

Please, how may this sentence be rephrased or improved to encapsulate the meaning in a more elegant way?

**Approaching *a more* patient-tailored N-staging of x cancer**

Specifically, it is the *a more* part I do not like. In my research paper, I have evaluated three commonly applied approaches to cancer staging and introduced a new approach that includes specific patient parameters to a greater extent than seen in the previous approaches.

Thank you in advance. Best.

Comment: You should understand "a more patient-tailored X" as "An X that is more tailored towards patients *than earlier [treatments]*" -- To tailor to/towards <noun> = to design so as to fit or suit <noun>. --  "More" = to a greater extent"

Comment: It sounds fine to me as it is. My degrees are in chemistry. Perhaps 'A more patient-tailored approach to an N-staging treatment of x cancer' is modest enough (the use of 'approach'); you need to decide on accuracy. Don't worry about 'a more patient-tailored': fine in a paper, but avoid it in the pub. Oh, we're avoiding the pub anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion "more" itself remains usable and useful.

Possibly the lack of idiomaticity felt in that title comes from the term "approaching". This title might sound  sharper once this word is replaced by "towards" (without doing away with the word "more"), a usual introductory preposition for titles in newspapers anyway, while using the plural of "N-staging".

- Towards more patient-tailored N-stagings for x cancer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

**Toward an N-staging idiopathic treatment of x cancer**

An [idiopathic disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiopathic_disease) is

> any disease with an unknown cause or mechanism of apparent spontaneous origin.

and

> approximately "a disease of its own kind"

I have read in scientific papers that breast cancers are idiopathic, and require individualized treatments, as opposed to a generic treatment.

Similar uses of *idiopathic treatment* may be found in:

- [Juvenile idiopathic arthritis and risk of cancer: A nationwide cohort study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/art.27741)
- [Idiopathic thrombocytopenic purpura in women with breast cancer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3082836/)